# EF Core Add-Migration error with invalid path not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I created a dbcontext net core proj, and also a web service net core proj (Proca.WebAPI) and ConfigureServices in startup.cs. Then I set the web service proj as start up proj and try to run "Add-Migration InitialCreate" in Package Manager Console. Then I got the following error:

> PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
>   The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'E:\git\Proca.Core\src\Proca.WebAPI\E:\git\Proca.Core\out\bin\Proca.WebAPI\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\' because it does not exist.

I am just confused that why the path is duplicate with prefix start up proj path. Is there anything wrong here or configuration missing? I also tried the dbcontext proj as start up proj and do the same but still got similar error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this question.

This is because the workmate set the output path in PropertyGroup (Directory.Build.props) and thus it result to this invalid path. After reset this value in csproj file it resolves the issue.

Comment: This is still useful to me. I'm trying to figure out from where EF gets the output path. I'm seeing the duplicated path and error too, but simply setting the <OutputPath> didn't work for me yet...

Comment: In the property setting file there may be many properties, and perhaps you can fill each with a constant value and check the error to identify which property leads to the error. Here are some properties that need to pay attention to:
<BaseOutputPath>$(BinFolder)/$(MSBuildProjectName)/$(Configuration)/$(Platform)/</BaseOutputPath>
        <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)</OutputPath>

Answer (score 0):

This is an older issue but I ran into it trying to use ef core 3.1 migration tools with a Directory.Build.props . Seems that ef core migration tool is concatenating the BaseIntermediateOutputPath and OutputPath because I would get the following error://

> "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot
> find path
> 'C:\code\MySolution\src\MyProject\C:\code\MySolution\build\bin\MyProject\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\'
> because it does not exist.

Note: my Project follows has the structure of C:\code\MySolutionFolder\src\MyProjectFolder and the build folder (C:\code\MySolutionFolder\build\) for output (bin) and intermediate (obj) is is two folders above (..\..\) the project folder.

Original:// Directory.Build.props

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)build\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)build\bin\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

WorkAround:// I used the following as a work around to use the ef core migration tools and still preserve my build process and folders. (replaced $(SolutionDir) with ..\..\ in the OutputPath)

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)build\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>..\..\build\bin\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```